# https, post and get via C++ and OpenSSL

Tags: c++, post, https, get

I am new to http/https. Before, our applications communicated through USB and serial COM ports, now we need to add support for https. Don't ask me why, it is a requirement, our application must be a server that pools the device, which will be the client. I have set an application to use OpenSSL libraries, but then I learned that it does not have functions for creating POST and GET messages. I am new to this, so I am not sure that my terminology is even correct.

We are on a short schedule, so is there any C++ library that can handle https POST and GET methods ? I know that libcurl can handle client connections as well as other libraries I saw here like Poco.

Is there any way of doing this without having to implement functions for formatting POST and GET messages ? If there is no way, I will eventually have to do it anyway, which will lead me to study this further, but as said, that is not the idea: we need a fast solution because this would not be the scope of the job. But if it is required to dig the http protocol deeper, I will have to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you either use

- [PoCo Network library](http://pocoproject.org/slides/200-Network.pdf) (HTTPServer HTTPClientSession and HTTPS by using the NetSSL library)
- Boost Asio with SSL

  - http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/client.cpp

Comment: Just curious: I have found a "easy-way" to install boost that is Boost pro http://www.boostpro.com/download/, from what I gather it already comes with the part of boost that needs to be compiled. I got to install it, but I want to install cpp-netblib and it seems cmake does not find the libraries that the boostpro installer already copied into my computer.

Comment: I usually copy the `/lib` dir somewhere and add it to the Library Directories for VC++ (or the VC++ Project assuming VS2010)

Comment: Yeah me too, but it seems it necessary to compile this cpp-netlib.

Comment: I am sticking to pure OpenSSL and writing my own POST and GET methods.

Comment: @zlogdan: ok, might be rational. Though in general I would **not** recommend that. Be prepared to deal with encodings, chunked encoding, keepalive, cache directives, HTTP302.x responses etc. **In short** do this only if you control both the server _and_ the client and you know what subset of HTTP you can limit it to

Comment: we have some control on both parts and the HTTP subset we need is only GET and POST messages, still, I am having to study http now. My knowledge is based on serial and USB protocols, and believe or not what I am having a hard time to get is how you format headers and bodies of this messages. Thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I am seeing a lot of drawbacks at doing it "by-hand". :-(

Comment: Mongoose was not working. I was told to modify the library, then I wasted time. I ended up hand coding my POST and GET treatment messages from raw usage of OpenSSL. I just need to put every session in a thread, that starts at request and ends after the session is done.

Comment: @zlogdan Okay. Mmm. No worries about the HTTP protocol features I mentioned, then? Thanks for updating this answer with your experiences

Comment: I think the key line was your comment "do this only if you control both the server and the client ", as we will only communicate one client and one server at once, as we aim to test the https communications.

Answer (score 0):

I did not use [`Wt`](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) much, but that's what comes to my mind when mentioning Web dev with C++ ! Maybe it is a possibility?

Comment: Not sure, I am completely ignorant on https.